# To check convergence of the sequence. I know Rate of growth of an exponential function is greater than a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials, convergence-divergence

Consider this sequence $$ a_n=(1+n)^{100}*e^{-√n}$$

Then sequence $<a_n>$ still follows that exponential term will be the dominating term being the exponent have a root?

I know exponential growth is higher than a polynomial function but here the exponential itself have a root in its power . It is the whole issue . I tried using L'Hôpital's rule & differentiate it 100 times & got a bunch of fractions but could not conclude anything. Tried using desmos to plot it ,it reaches infinity. But everyone I have asked say that it will converge to 0 because of the denominator as exponential.Then I plotted numerator & denominator separately & see where they intersect & exponential function crosses the polynomial & become dominating term .But they intersect only at 0 & 0.0001 & rest the denominator curve lags behind the numerator curve i.e. polynomial. Suggestions will be appreciated [this is their graph plotted by desmos, behaviour of the two functions in the graph is same for higher values of x too as is zoomed out as it is limit in software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wty47.jpg)

Comment: Your $a_n$ has no n in it? if x=n than use the series for the exponential function for exponent >100.

Comment: Apologies, I was working on it on plotting it on desmos so interchanged n by x , but edited that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a sense of the end behavior of the function, we can substitute $n^2$ for $n$ as when $n^2$ approaches infinity $n$ also approaches infinity for positive values of $n$. With that we get $(1+n^2)^{100}e^{-\sqrt{n^2}}$. Rearranging and simplifying we get $\frac{(1+n^2)^{100}}{e^n}$ and keeping only the highest order terms we get $\frac{n^{200}}{e^n}$. Since, as previously mentioned, the exponential term is stronger than the polynomial term, the limit as n approaches infinity is 0.

The reason that Desmos doesn't show this is because by the time the value starts decreasing again, the values involved are too much for it to handle and so they will not be graphed (If you tell Desmos to calculate a value like $a_{1000000}$ explicitly, it simply returns an error). The numerator and denominator do, in fact, equal each other at around $n=2.12*10^6$. This can be found by taking the logarithm of both sides to get [$100ln(n+1)=\sqrt{n}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=100*ln%28x%2B1%29%3Dsqrt%28x%29) so that the numbers aren't so big.

Comment: (+1) Strictly speaking, your argument for $\lim a_n=0$ is not complete: you only proved that the *subsequence* $(a_{n^2})$ converges to $0.$ This can easily be fixed by saying that $a_n=f(\sqrt n)$ for a *function* $f$ such that $\lim_{+\infty}f=0.$

Comment: This gives me hint that if I consider the given sequence as a series instead,whose sequence off partial sum is this given $<a <sub>n</sub> $ then apply logarithmic test for convergence of series & if that series converge then by necessary condition of convergence say that limit ( x tends to ∞) SOPS is zero. Is this approach right?